# Copy and paste cell values (not formulae) from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste the values of a large number of cells from one sheet to another. I tried

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z150").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Backup").Range("A1")`

It copies the formulae instead.

Adding `.Value` results in the error `Object required`.

I also tried.

`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z150").Value = Sheets("Backup").Range("A1").Value`

How do I copy cell values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z150").Copy
Sheets("Backup").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thanks, that did the job!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `value`, both ranges should be of the same size:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z150").Value = Sheets("Backup").Range("A1:Z150").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Address property of Range object to be sure to reference the same address in different ranges:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z150")
    Sheets("Backup").Range(.Address).Value = .Value
End With
```